# Insert items into RecyclerView after activity is visible

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

I have an activity with nested recyclerviews and overall about 100 entries which I get from a SQLite database. On the emulator the activity takes about a half second to open up but on my personal phone it takes multible seconds.

So I had the idea to start the activity with empty recyclerviews. Then the entries should be added while showing a loading spinner.

My idea was to use an `AsyncTask` which looks like this:

```
private final class LoadItems extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Item>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Item> doInBackground(String... params) {
        final ArrayList<Item> items = DBHelper.getItems();
        adapter.setItems(items);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super.onPostExecute(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

In `doInBackground` the sql SELECT requests are made and a ArrayList with the objects is passed to the already existing (but empty) adapter. The `setItems` method from the adapter replaces the ArrayList inside the adapter. In `onPostExecute` `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called to update the recyclerview.

**I tried to execute the AsyncTask inside onCreate and onResume but in both cases the activity started after seconds with the recyclerview items already loaded**. Strangely enough, adding Thread.sleep(2000) to the AsyncTask led to the expected result, loading the recyclerview after the activity opened.

However I came up with the following idea:

```
recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
                LoadItems loadItems = new LoadItems();
                loadItems.execute(null);


            }
        });
```

This works as intended but I am not sure whether it's the right way. Also it doesn't work that great with two AsyncTask loading two recyclerviews.

```
LoadItems loadItems1 = new LoadItems();
LoadItems loadItems2 = new LoadItems();

loadItems1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, null);
loadItems2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, null);
```

If the first one is loaded already and I click on an item which opens a new activity the activity is opened only after the second recyclerview is loaded completely.

Comment: Why do you start your Tasks with "executeOnExecutor" and not with just "execute"?

Comment: @LucaMurra I think otherwise they run after each other and not parallel